# How does this function work?

Tags: ruby

The `ordered_vowel_words` method and `ordered_vowel_word?` helper method accept a word and return the word back if the vowels of the word are in the order of (a,e,i,o,u).

I'm having trouble understanding the logic. Particularly how the last block `(0...(vowels_arr.length - 1)).all? do...` in the helper method works.

Can someone please explain how this works? I don't understand how `all?` is being called on a `range`.

```
def ordered_vowel_words(str)
  words = str.split(" ")

  ordered_vowel_words = words.select do |word|
    ordered_vowel_word?(word)
  end

  ordered_vowel_words.join(" ")
end

def ordered_vowel_word?(word)
  vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

  letters_arr = word.split("")
  vowels_arr = letters_arr.select { |l| vowels.include?(l) }

  (0...(vowels_arr.length - 1)).all? do |i|
    vowels_arr[i] <= vowels_arr[i + 1]
  end
end
```

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added some comments :)

```
def ordered_vowel_words(str)
  # words is a string with words separated by a whitespace.
  # split generates an array of words from a string
  words = str.split(" ")

  # select only the ordered vowel words from the previous array
  ordered_vowel_words = words.select do |word|
    ordered_vowel_word?(word)
  end

  # join the ordered vowel words in a single string
  ordered_vowel_words.join(" ")
end

def ordered_vowel_word?(word)
  # THESE ARE THE VOWELS YOU FOOL
  vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

  # transform the word in an array of characters
  letters_arr = word.split("")

  # select only the vowels in this array
  vowels_arr = letters_arr.select { |l| vowels.include?(l) }

  # generate a range from 0 to the length of the vowels array minus 2:
  # there is this weird range because we want to iterate from the first vowel
  # to the second to last; all? when called on a range returns true if...
  (0...(vowels_arr.length - 1)).all? do |i|
    # for each number in the range, the current vowel is smaller that the next vowel
    vowels_arr[i] <= vowels_arr[i + 1]
  end
end
```

Hope this helped!

**EDIT** I might add that the last block doesn't feel very Ruby-ish. I may suggest this alternative implementation:

```
def ordered_vowel_word?(word)
  vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

  # transform the word in an array of characters
  letters_arr = word.split("")

  # select only the vowels in this array
  vowels_arr = letters_arr.select { |l| vowels.include?(l) }

  # from this array generate each possible consecutive couple of characters 
  vowels_arr.each_cons(2).all? do |first, second|
    first <= second
  end
end

require 'rspec/autorun'

describe "#ordered_vowel_word?" do
  it "tells if word is ordered" do
    expect(ordered_vowel_word?("aero")).to be_true
  end

  it "or not" do
    expect(ordered_vowel_word?("rolling")).to be_false
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks "FOOL!" :) -- Your comments helped me realize something. I jumped into `irb` and I tried `"a" < "e"` and I got back `true`. I forgot about that. Now I understand what `(0...(vowels_arr.length - 1)).all? do |i| vowels_arr[i] <= vowels_arr[i + 1]` is doing. I couldn't figure how it was able to determine if the order was correct. Well now I realized `a < e < i < o < u`. Thanks pal! By the way - Italy is my home country, lucky you for being there!

Comment: I've added also a more Ruby-ish implementation, with passing tests :) Ciao bello!

Comment: The alternative is delightful. Very nice! Grazie, Arrivederci!

Answer (score 0):

The `all?` block is essentially iterating over the `vowels_arr` array, comparing each value with it's next one. If all the comparisons return `true` then `all?` will also return `true`, which means the array is ordered. If one of the iterations returned `false`, the return value of `all?` would also be `false`, which would mean that the collection is unordered.

You can call `all?` on a Rangehttp://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html object because `Range` mixes in the Enumerablehttp://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html module, which is the one that defines `all?`.

You can verify this by trying the following in irb:

```
Range.included_modules # => => [Enumerable, Kernel]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The first part `(0...(vowels_arr.length - 1))` creates a range from
   0 to how many vowels are in the word.
2. `all?` iterates over that range and returns `true` if all for all
   elements of the range some condition is true false otherwise.
3. `do |i|` introduces a block with `i` as the variable representing
   each element of the range created in step 1.
4. Finally, the condition is for each index in the range, now represented by `i`, it checks if `vowels_arr[i] <= vowels_arr[i+1]` is true.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to this problem:

```
def ordered_vowel_words(str)
  vowels_s = str.scan(/[aeiou]/)
  vowels_sort = str.scan(/[aeiou]/).sort
  vowels_s === vowels_sort ? str : ""
end
```